# Apache RewriteRule - unable to match start of string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to match a url using regex in a .htaccess file.

I am able to match the end of the string using "$" just fine, but when I try to match the start of the string using "^", the RewriteRule stops working.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^example-url$" "index.php"
```

Without the "^" the regex will work, but is too lax. I've fiddled with this for a couple of hours now, but I'm not sure what else to try, since this very basic regex, that has worked in every regex tester I've tried.

My best guess atm is that it has something to do with what the start of the string actually is, but I'm not sure how to test this, since it should start just after the top level domain name with the "/".

**EDIT:**
Moving the .htaccess to the html folder made all my problems go away, the above .htaccess file now works fine. Thanks so much for the help @Riad Loukili and @P0lT10n.

I'm guessing my problems were caused by the way my virtual directories are setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^example-url$ index.php
```

I tried it on [This .htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) and it worked.

**Possible Explanation**: You've already specified the RewriteBase, no need to start the url with / in the Regular Expression.

Comment: That is the problem, he is trying to match `//example` not `/example` because he already defined `RewriteBase`

Comment: @Riad Loukili Thanks for the reply. Just tried that, but it seems to act like the rule isn't there at all.

Comment: @P0lT10n I don't have very much experience with 'RewriteRule', so I may have this wrong. I thought the 'RewriteBase' command affects the internal path, and not the external path? Does it affect both or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @Andrew As far as I know, RewriteBase affects only the "external path", it has nothing to do with the "internal path", So if you dont't have any other Rewrite Conditions, you may just remove the `RewriteBase ` line and add a / in the beginning of the uri. And don't hesitate testing your .htaccess with any online .htaccess tester. I hope that could help.

Comment: @Riad Loukili According to the .htaccess tester you posted this code is valid: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?example-url/?$ index.php`  
I'm still currently unable to get it working.

Comment: @Riad Loukili I've tried removing the `RewriteBase`, and I found that `index.php` had to become `html/index.php`

Comment: the .htaccess file is in the same folder as the index.php ?

Comment: @Riad Loukili .htaccess and index.php are in different folders, htaccess in root, and the index.php in html

Comment: They are both treated with absolute URL if you use `RewriteBase /`

Comment: @Andrew, not sure but try `RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^example-url$ html/index.php` instead

Comment: @Riad Loukili @P0lT10n I was able to get it working with this: `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^html/example-url$ html/index.php`

Comment: @Riad Loukili I'll try your suggestion, as I'd still like to get working with `RewriteBase /`. I currently don't understand why the external path has to start with html/ without `RewriteBase /`, as the external path doesn't map to anything meaningful server side anyway.